# How do I format spaces in java as well as add a leading 0 before a two digit number, to convert in it to a 3 digit number?

Tags: java, format

Question:

Input:

java 100
cpp 65
python 50

Output:

java           100
cpp            065
python         050

"Each String is left-justified with trailing whitespace through the first  characters. The leading digit of the integer is the  character, and each integer that was less than  digits now has leading zeroes."

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: Ive tried System.out.printf("%20d%", (variable));

This was to add the spaces

Answer (score 2):

Default formatting:

```
String.format("%d", 93); // prints 93
```

Specifying a width:

```
String.format("|%20d|", 93); // prints: |                  93|
```

Left-justifying within the specified width:

```
String.format("|%-20d|", 93); // prints: |93                  |
```

Pad with zeros:

```
String.format("|%020d|", 93); // prints: |00000000000000000093|
```